# What are some good resources on medieval German culture and mythology?

Tags: worldbuilding-resources

I'm writing a book about the Pied Piper, and I was wondering if anyone has any good recommendations for books, websites, etc., about German culture in the 1200s - all aspects of German culture: religion, politics, clothing, food, music - and also German mythology, specifically that focusing on mythical creatures (and preferably not the Grimms' Fairy Tales, as I have my own collection of those). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struwwelpeter) 1845 -- children's morality tales -- scary but typical. Not mythology, but a good book.

Comment: Hi, welcome to worldbuilding! I believe (someone can correct me if I'm wrong) that things like book recommendations are off topic here - it's impossible to tell which answer (which recommendation) is better, so is (for one) opinion based, which we don't really like (sorry). If you have a specific question about medieval German culture, the [History stack exchange](http://history.stackexchange.com) would be a good place to ask. Otherwise, if you have a specific question about building a world, we'd be very happy to help here. Also @AngelPray, recommendation questions are off-topic on literature

Comment: Upon further looking into this, book recommendations aren't actually off-topic, but in this case, I believe it would probably be helpful if the question were more specific - see [here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2542/19951) and [here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2545/19951) for more detailed discussions about what makes a good recommendation question. Sorry if I'm causing any confusion and good luck on your search!

Comment: I can see the need to look for good material. When I wrote the book for my musical, we basically used research to create a world on the stage. That's no different from asking what items would be needed if we were to settle on Mars. Instead of looking for/recommending books, you'd be looking at scientific research, peer review papers, and TV documentaries. I think the questioner is asking as I did way back because the world I created on stage had to be my own, but it also needed to be somewhat true to the story. You can take this story, change a few things, and create a great SiFi world.

Answer (score 2):

Back in 1977 I wrote a musical about the Pied Piper of Hamlin. It was produced in 1978 at a children's festival in New Jersey and made it to off-off-Broadway in 1979.

I wish I had the Internet back then, but the story dates back to 1384 if I recall from a Wikipedia link that lists all the books, at least the important ones that advanced and even changed the story over time.

You can find the list of books at [List of literary accounts of the Pied Piper](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_literary_accounts_of_the_Pied_Piper)

And I found some interesting versions of it on websites. Just do a search.

Note: I would have rather put this in as a comment, but I lack 7 reputation points. Sorry moderators if this answer does not meet requirements.